# Dendrogram from hierarchical clustering in D3

Tags: d3.js, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I'm quite new to D3 so I apologize if this is a very basic question. I wish to implement a dendrogram that shows the result of a hierarchical clustering algorithm. This layout differs in a major point from the examples I have been able to find: Except for the leaves of the tree, the nodes does not have any identity, but merely joins subtrees at specific heights relative to their like-ness.

As an example look at:

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/file/n2293207/Dendrogram.jpeg

Compared to http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570 this dendrogram does not have the 'n-partite nature' (defined layers for each level of nodes).

The question is thus how to define a dendrogram with arbitrary join positions of subtrees?

Thanks

Thomas

**edit:**

It seems it was not as difficult as anticipated and it did not require development of a new layout. In my input data I included an additional parameter with the calculated height of the join. An example json file would be something like this:

```
{
 "height": "1",
 "children": [
              {
               "height": "0.8",
               "children": [
                            {
                             "name": "leaf 1",
                             "height": "0"
                            },
                            {
                             "height": "0.35",
                             "children": [
                                          {
                                           "name": "leaf 2",
                                           "height": "0"
                                          },
                                          {
                                           "name": "leaf 3",
                                           "height": "0"
                                          }
                                         ]
                           ]
              },
              {
               "name": "leaf 4",
               "height": "0"
              }
             ]
}
```

and then, when calculating the node object, transform the y value using map:

```
var nodes = cluster.nodes(root).map(function(d) {d.y = scale(d.height); return d});
```

where cluster is your cluster layout object and scale is a suitable scale for the dendrogram height.

Comment: None of the layouts in D3 support what you want to do. The dendrogram in the example is not the same kind of dendrogram that you want to produce. I'm afraid you'd have to implement the layout for your dendrogram yourself.

Comment: Hmm - I feared that. Oh well, the best way to learn a tool is to be forced to improve it :-). I will update this post when I have developed the layout.

Comment: There were some attempts to implement diagrams like yours with d3. One of them is [Phylogenetic Tree of Life](http://www.jasondavies.com/tree-of-life/)

Comment: What library are you using?